# Цепные вызовы методов с передачей значений от предыдущего следующему

Tags: ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Мне нужно сделать цепочку вызов с передачей возвращеных значений от предыдущего метода к следующему. Вызов по цепочке, это pattern Commands, но вот с передачей возвращеного значения у меня проблема, у меня получается, какой-то адский pattern.

```
var commands:Commands = new Commands()
.run(method1) // этот метод возвращает значение
.then(method2) // которое нужно обработать здесь и вернуть полученный результат
.then(method3); // чтобы обработать его здесь
```

Как такое можно сделать? Есть у этого правильное название?

Comment: И что с чем тут асинхронно взаимодействует?

Comment: Вот если честно, то не понимаю я таких абстракций.

--

Допустим, на Си (хотя он не слишком подходит для обобщенного программирования) я бы сделал список из адресов функций, принимающих и возвращающих `void *`.

Тогда функция `void *run(void *first_arg, fu_list foo);` просто пробегала бы по списку и вызывала функции по хранимому адресу, передавая результат предыдущей в следующую.

Наверное, аналогично можно написать на любом языке, который даже как-то абстрагирует адреса исполняемого кода и участков памяти.

Comment: В JavaScript, в частности, в плагиинах jQuery, принято возвращать тот же объект, метод которого вызываем. Для передачи параметров можно менять свойства этого объекта.

Comment: > правильное название?

Может вы имели в виду **Fluent interface** [[en][1]], [[ru][2]]


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface
  [2]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface

Comment: @vas, тут может быть только один конкретный ответ: OOP is Evil!

Никогда не читали таких материалов и не задумывались о качестве современного ПО?

Comment: @vas, заметьте, что о производительности (в секундах, байтах и т.п.) я ни слова не сказал.

--

Проблема тут глубже. Обратите внимание, что за последние 20 (а скорее 30) лет в области именно программирования почти нет качественных прорывов (аналогичных \*nix, оконным системам и интернету (гипертекст + сеть + браузер)). М.б. за исключением успехов ИИ, основанных на BigData.

Т.е. именно за время, когда ООП (*вместе со всеми шаблонами*) стало основой в преподавании программирования и дальше в разработке ПО.

И в результате мы получили слишком большое количество стандартно мыслящих разработчиков

Comment: Теперь по поводу Вашей задачи.

Если я правильно понял, то нужно вызывать методы не непрерывным потоком, а при возникновении некоторых событий, при условии, что входные данные, произведенные предыдущим вызовом другого метода в цепочке готовы. Так?

Тогда для каждого такого метода можно организовать свою очередь аргументов, в которую помещается результат другого метода. Плюс диспетчер этих очередей. 

По сути это похоже на реализацию main-loop в оконной системе, когда поступившее событие проходит по  иерархии виджетов.

А паттерн -- наверное какая-то разновидность подписчика (или чего там?).

Comment: @avp, после таких слов Вы должны поклясться, что больше не используете не один шаблон, в своей практике!) Можно ещё и математику и даже алгоритмы забыть, а то это тоже однообразие.  Это все конечно юмор, но смысл в том, что программирование это точная наука и шаблоны в нем равны законам в математике, а не клетками в тетради, с которыми Вы их сравниваете.